# Macro to allocate x Rows of Data to x Number of People and then color code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a task I perform I'm looking to automate for a relatively large set of data.
Basically, I have a list of records that I need to assign out to a group of people and then color code those assignments accordingly.

There is no set count of how many records there will be, so the number of rows is a variable.
The number of people is also a variable.

The Records are in column A.
The People are in Column E.

If there are 1000 records and 20 people, then assign 50 records per person by entering their name in column C.

So how can I create a macro that will:

1- count the Number of Records and divide by the Number of People

2- use that number as the number of records to assign each person and input the person's name in column C

3- assign each person with a different Fill Color and Font Color to help distinguish between one another.  (is it possible to assign the same color scheme for each name in column C as well as column E?)

here's a sample of what I'm looking to accomplish

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This looks like Excel. Are you using Excel or a database?

Comment: i'm using Excel. i should remove the database tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s an interesting project.  The code below will give you (mostly) what you’re looking for.  The issue with formatting is that, whereas it’s possible to generate random formats – you could end up with (e.g.) green on green which is unusable.  The code therefore copies whatever formats you set on each person’s name in column E to all of the corresponding cells in column C.

I tested the following code with 10,000 records & 17 people each with different formats.  It ran in under 1 second.  Let me know how you go with it.

```
Option Explicit
Sub AssignTasks()
Dim Records As Long, PasteTo As Long, People As Integer, LastP As Long
Dim balance As Integer, base As Integer, hard As Integer, p As Range
Dim AllRng As Range, BaseStart As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
People = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
If People <> 1 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C" & People).Clear
End If

People = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
On Error Resume Next
ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & People).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
On Error GoTo 0

Records = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row - 1
People = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row - 1

base = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Records / People, 0)
balance = Records - (People * base)
hard = base + 1

ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & balance + 1).Name = "hardrng"
ActiveSheet.Range("E" & balance + 2 & ":E" & People + 1).Name = "easyrng"

If balance = 0 Then GoTo SkipHard

For Each p In ActiveSheet.Range("hardrng")    
    PasteTo = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set AllRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & PasteTo)
    AllRng.Resize(hard, 1).Value = p.Value    
Next p

SkipHard:
For Each p In ActiveSheet.Range("easyrng")    
    PasteTo = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set AllRng = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & PasteTo)
    AllRng.Resize(hard - 1, 1).Value = p.Value    
Next p

'Copy the formats
People = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
LastP = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For Each p In ActiveSheet.Range("E2:E" & People)        
    Sheet1.Range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="" & p
    p.Copy
    On Error Resume Next
        Sheet1.Range("C2:C" & LastP).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlFormats            
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.CutCopyMode = False    
Next p

Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Note that you say the records are in column A, but your image shows them in column B. This code uses column B - easily changed.

Comment: wow. thanks so much.
i'm reading through the code to try to understand how it works and this will really be useful to me as i progress in vba..
very clever solution with the formatting.

i'm getting a Compile error: Syntax error on this section, as it copies the formats from column E..any ideas why?

Sheet1.Range("C2:C" & LastP).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial ,
        Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Comment: Does the code run up to that point & then stop - or will it not run at all?

Comment: it doesn't run at all, so i deleted the "Copy the formats" portion and it works perfectly otherwise.  this thing is beautiful man, thanks so much

Comment: yep. works like a charm.
curious though, how come for this section you refer to the tab as Sheet1.Range, as opposed to ActiveSheet.Range?

Comment: You're quite right, should have used one or the other throughout. Sheet1 would have been best.

Comment: i have another problem i'm trying to solve but hard for me to explain without uploading the file...do you mind if i email you?  no worries if not and no worries if you can't help - just thought i'd ask as i have no idea how to go about it

Comment: By all means - email away.